# is there any inmemmory MapReduce techniques in opensource

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to find techniques to make hadoop faster.Is there any 'inmemory hadoop mapreduce' techniques in 'open source' like gridgain? For gridgain i am only able to download evaluation version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for [Apache Spark](http://spark.incubator.apache.org/).

```
To run programs faster, Spark offers a general execution model 
that can optimize arbitrary operator graphs, and supports in-memory 
computing, which lets it query data faster than disk-based engines like Hadoop.
```

It is a bit different to code though, as it was mainly designed for `Scala`. So you don't write `map` and `reduce` functions anymore, but declaratively build blocks of your computations- thus `Spark` is a lot more flexible than `MapReduce`.

Let's take a look at WordCount, the Java version looks a bit verbose:

```
 JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> ones = words.map(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
      public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
        return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
      }
    });

    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = ones.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
      public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        return i1 + i2;
      }
    });
```

Maybe it will get better with the Java 8 features.

In `Scala` it is much more compact:

```
val file = spark.textFile("hdfs://...")
val counts = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                  .map(word => (word, 1))
                  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
counts.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://...")
```